# Data reload in IBM maximo anywhere apps

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I just had a generic question related to IBM Maximo Anywhere apps, as per my understanding, data gets locally stored on a device at the time you log in to the app. I was curious to know that if something changes on the Maximo side, or if there is a refresh of data on device, will the entire set of data be replaced with a fresh pull from Maximo or is it just going to be the parts that were modified and the rest remains the same? If its just a delta refresh, how does Anywhere decide what has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "transactional" data like workorders, we download the whole list but have code that merges in the records from the server with your local copies and preserves any local changes you might have pending that haven't been sent to the server yet.

For lookup data (like assets and locations), on refresh, we remove all the local lookup data and replace it from the server.